# Jquery - Apply rule if item contains one string OR another string

Tags: jquery

Hopefully I can explain this better than I can Google it!

I have a Jquery rule that detects a certain word then applies a class to that elements parent container which works as hoped.
Instead of simply duplicating this rule for additional words I would like to just include them in the rule effectively as an "OR".

This is what I have that works:-

```
$(".container:contains(Word1)").each(function(){
    $(this).closest("#containerParent").addClass("newClass");
    });
```

This is the none-working attempt:-

```
$(".container:contains(Word1)"|".container:contains(Word2)").each(function(){
    $(this).closest("#containerParent").addClass("newClass");
    });
```

As an alternative I could make it a function of course, but I would like to do it "properly" or in a cleaner way.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(".container:contains(Word1), .container:contains(Word2)").each(function(){
    $(this).closest("#containerParent").addClass("newClass");
});
```

Comment: Oh boy! I'm kicking myself. Why on earth I didn't think to use a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just a comma?

[Multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: As above. I specifically use Jquery because of its similarity to CSS, I don't know why I didn't try using a comma. Thanks the the reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit `or` selector. You can either just use another selector and seperate those with a `,`, or use `.filter()` like

```
$('.container').filter(function() {
    return /Word1|Word2/.test( this.textContent );
}).closest( '.containerParent' ).addClass( 'newClass' );
```

Reference: [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

By the way, it seems a little wierd to look for an `id` with `.closest()`, since IDs have to be unique in a html markup.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that I'm having a bit of a dim day, of course there's only one ID. Thanks for your help :)